# Google Maps API - Marker not showing

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add markers for every single row from a table, that sits on the page. The page is http://www.sravanks.com/first/2013ftcmap.php

This is the JS code that's loading the markers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.740, -89.503),
  zoom: 7
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

/* City Markers */
var cityCircle = new Array();
var i = 0;
$.each($('.events tr'), function(index, value) {
    var name = $(this).find('td:first()').html();
    var address = $(this).find('.address').html();
    var linkUrl = "http://www.sravanks.com/first/geocode.php?address=" + address;

    $.ajax({
        url: linkUrl
    }).done(function(data){
        var json = $.parseJSON(data.substring(0, data.length-1));

        lat = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        lng = json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, map: map, icon: 'map-pointer-medium.gif' });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(name);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            cityCircle[i] = new google.maps.Circle({strokeColor: '#00FF00', strokeOpacity: 0.8, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: '#00FF00', fillOpacity: 0.35, map: map, center: latlng, radius: 144841});
                           i++;
        });

    });
});

/*Team Markers*/
var markers = {};
var teamName, teamNumber, lat, lng, content;
$.each($('.list tr'), function(index, value) {
    teamName = $(this).find('td.name').html();
    teamNumber = $(this).find('td.number').html();

    markers[teamNumber] = {};

    lat = parseFloat($(this).find('td.lat').html());
    lng = parseFloat($(this).find('td.lng').html());

    content = "Name: " + teamName + "<br />Number: " + teamNumber;
    markers[teamNumber]['latlng'] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    markers[teamNumber]['marker'] = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markers[teamNumber]['latlng'], map: map });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[teamNumber]['marker'], 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, markers[teamNumber]['marker']);
    });
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
                      for(var i=0;i<cityCircle.length;i++){
                            cityCircle[i].setMap(null);
                       }
});
});
```

I've got no errors, but the Team Markers do not show up. The strange thing is that the City Markers do show up.

Some more info, the City Markers ajax call is just to a proxy that calls the google geocoding api. Again the link's at http://www.sravanks.com/first/2013ftcmap.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Team Markers do show up but all of them are somewhere in Turkey or Georgia because table of team data has error for lat/lng:

```
<tr>
<td class="number">111</td>
<td class="name">MiniStang</td>
<td class="address">Schaumburg, IL 60196 USA</td>
<td class="lat">42.070247650146</td>
<td class="lng">42.070247650146</td>
</tr>
```

Note the latitude and longitude values. They have **the same number**. Longitude should be something like -87.62806429999999. So you have to fix you table generator.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.